# UIAlertView deprecated?

Tags: swift, xcode, alert, deprecated

I want to use an alert box with a "Ok" button to return to the previous view controller.

I use this code :

```
let alert = UIAlertView(title: "",
                            message: "bla",
                            delegate: nil,
                            cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
alert.show()
```

But Xcode says that it is deprecated, so I've tried this :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Button", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but the Alert Box won't display...
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any `Attempt to present <UIAlertController: ...> on <ViewController: ....> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use swift 3 you can try this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Button", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) for more detail.

Comment: Its not working, I don't know why but it seems that the problem is my Xcode configuration. I have maid my own alertView class based on UIView